# Hole detection on ROS with a stereo camera

Tags: ros, c++, point-cloud

I am trying to make a node in ROS that has as input a dynamic point cloud that is generated with a stereoscopic camera to which I have performed preprocessing. Now that point cloud that is generated usually has holes which I should detect. I've been working with PCL for a couple of months looking for a way to detect these holes in real time but I still haven't succeeded. Could someone suddenly give me a suggestion or recommendation to address this issue

Comment: Could you elaborate on what sort of hole are you trying to identify? A picture will be great.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* JhonathanR, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Without more focus and clarity, this is sounding like an *Unbounded Design Question* and at risk of being closed.

Comment: @JhonathanR: can you start defining at first, what you mean for _hole_ in the PCL?